# SQL Server encryption with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption

I am trying the encrypt multiple column. I need to help for my code. It's crashing at cursor statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[encrypt] (@stringtosplit nvarchar(500))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @splitWord NVARCHAR(255)    
DECLARE @pos  INT
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar (255)
DECLARE @columnName  nvarchar (255)
DECLARE @sqlQueryForEncryption nvarchar(500) 
DECLARE @encKey nvarchar(255)

    DECLARE cursorSplit cursor for select @splitWord from dbo.splitstring (@stringtosplit)



        OPEN cursorSplit 
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorSplit
        INTO @splitWord


        SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @splitWord)
        SELECT @tableName = SUBSTRING( @splitWord, 1, @pos-1 )
        SET @columnName = SUBSTRING(@splitWord,@pos,LEN(@splitWord)-LEN(@tableName))

        SET @enckey = KEY_GUID('enc_sym_key') 

        OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY enc_sym_key  DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE enc_cert

            SET @sqlQueryForEncryption = 'UPDATE' + @tablename + 'SET'+ '' + @columnName +''+'= EncryprtByKey KEY_GUID'+ @encKey + ',' +@columnName 

            EXECUTE (@sqlQueryForEncryption) 

        CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY enc_sym_key;

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorSplit

        CLOSE cursorSplit2
DEALLOCATE cursorSplit2


    CLOSE cursorSplit
DEALLOCATE cursorSplit

END



ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([splitWord] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @fullWord NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(';' , @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(';', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @fullWord = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @fullWord

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit


 RETURN
END
```

Comment: This whole approach is problematic. Let's start at the beginning, your splitter. Looping here is horribly inefficient. You need to replace that with a set based splitter. My personal favorite is here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ And this link has several other excellent options. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: I don't think you need a cursor here either but the reason your code is crashing is because your dynamic sql is invalid. You should ALWAYS do a print/select of dynamic sql before executing it when you build things like this. Had you done that you would have realized that your dynamic sql looks something like this: "UPDATEMyTableSetMyColumn= EncryprtByKy...". Encrypt is spelled incorrectly and you don't have any spaces in your update statement.